# How do I store an integer using ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: java, orm, coldfusion, integer, coldfusion-2016

## TL:DR;

What's the proper syntax/workaround/hack for CF ORM components which have foreign key constraints?

---

### ColdFusion + Integers

Storing a variable as an integer should be an easy programming question, right? Find the appropriate function in the language's documentation (if you can't recall it off the dome) which will say *returns: int* (owtte) and use that.

Not with ColdFusion.

Some of you may already be aware of ColdFusion's [various issues with integers](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/can-we-please-agree-that-adobe-is-not.html) but the one which is currently causing my rapid hair-loss is that ColdFusion will sometimes store your "integer" as either a string, double or long. Now, for most use cases this is not a functionality-breaking issue and is often overlooked/ignored/undiscovered. The exception, in my case, is when ORM comes into play. Of course, as any sensible developer would, I am recognising the possibility of this being down to user error somewhere.

---

### The Problem

The problem occurs whenever CF attempts to interact with the DB. If there is a field which is a foreign key and type 'integer', CF throws a Hibernate Exception with the following message:

`java.lang.Integer`

That's it. Helpful, right? I found out that this "error message" is explicitly the variable type you're passing into that field, so if you pass a double into the field erroneously, the error message would read `java.lang.Double`.

Now, this seems to be less about the field itself and more to do with related components - this only happens on a field which has a foreign key constraint linking it to an integer field somewhere else.

Basic example of the kind of thing I'm going for:

**Template.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="template"{

    property name="id"              type="numeric"  sqltype="integer"   column="templateID" fieldtype="id"  generator="identity";
    property name="userID"          type="numeric"  sqltype="integer"   fkcolumn="userID"           fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="User";
    property name="lastModified"    type="date"     sqltype="timestamp" column="lastModified";

}
```

**User.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="user"{

    property name="id"          type="numeric"  sqltype="integer"   column="userID"     fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="username"    type="string"   sqltype="nvarchar"  column="username";
    property name="password"    type="string"   sqltype="nvarchar"  column="password";

}
```

The problem occurs when flushing the ORM having updated `template.userID`.

---

### Things I've tried

- Contacting Adobe CF Support (we have an enterprise licence with platinum support, but in a month they haven't been able to give me a solution or even any information beyond "it's not working?")
- Adding the `ormtype` attribute to identity fields (and then foreign key fields when that didn't work)
- Changing the `sqltype` property (which I now believe [is only for table creation](https://cfdocs.org/cfproperty#p-cacheUse) which we never needed anyway since the database was already in place)
- Converting the variable using various combinations of the following functions:

  - `NumberFormat( var )` - documentation says it returns 'A formatted number value', actually returns a `java.lang.String`
  - `LSParseNumber( var )`- returns a double
  - `Int( var )` - This one's great: documentation says it returns an **integer**, as a **string**. Actually returns a `java.lang.Double`
  - `Val( var )` - returns a double
  - `javaCast( 'int', var )` - returns an integer, which throws the same error
- Setting the `elementtype` attribute on the property (both ends)
- Relaxing the `validate` attribute on the property (both ends) to 'numeric'

I suspect this *may* be to do with a combination of Hibernate and CF, rather than just CF, and dispite it's javascript-reminiscent quirks, I still love it.

---

### Environment

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- ColdFusion 2016 (Enterprise)
- SQL Server

Comment: Is the column you are saving the data an integer?

Comment: In the database (Environment updated - thanks for that) the column is `int`

Comment: If the solution was update the DB, then that should be worked up as an answer

Comment: It wasn't, I was just letting you know the column in the database is `int` - the thanks was for helping me realise I hadn't already added the DB to my Environment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL:DR;

Pass the entity, not the ID.
A foreign key property in CF ORM referencing persistent entity Foo is of type Foo and not int.

### More detail

After all this time, Adobe passed me around a few people until I landed on an engineer who knew what he was talking about. It turns out the problem is not so much with the ORM engine (Hibernate) not recognising the integer as an integer, but if you have a foreign key which references another persistent entity, then you must pass **the entity** and not the ID.

### Example (in context of the question)

First, I've removed the `type` and `sqltype` values from the question, since the former can be retrieved by CF inspecting the DB (which in my case is fine, but you may have to explicitly set it, especially if you've turned off `useDBforMapping` in Application.cfc).

Second, I've renamed the `userID` property in the Template component to `user`, as it may help those that don't immediately understand what I said above about 'passing the entity' to visualise it better.

**Template.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="template"{

    property name="id"              column="templateID"      fieldtype="id"          generator="identity";
    property name="user"            fkcolumn="userID"        fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="User";
    property name="lastModified"    column="lastModified";

}
```

**User.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="user"{

    property name="id"          column="userID"     fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="username"    column="username";
    property name="password"    column="password";

}
```

So, lets say you know the ID of the user who is associated with this template (maybe they're the creator, for example). What you have to do is, not pass the ID to the `user` property, but rather create a User component, then pass *that*.

**index.cfm**

```
userID = 4; // Example user ID, which we got from somewhere earlier in the code

templateID = 20; // Example template ID, which we got from somewhere earlier in the code

// Create template entity (loading by primary key)
template = EntityLoadByPK( 'Template', templateID );

// To set the user in the Template entity, we must pass a User entity
user = EntityLoadByPK( 'User', userID );

// Only then can we successfully update the template's foreign key property
template.setUser( user );
EntitySave( template );

// Line below is not usually needed, but it forces DB interaction so it's 
// useful in the context of this example
ORMFlush();
```

Hope this helps anyone else who happens across the same confusion.

JC